# storage link doesn't work after moving project directory

Tags: laravel, hyperlink, storage

I have tried php artisan storage:link again , i have changed the public directories, it's happening after moving the folder to another drive.

The file system config:

```
    'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
       ],
```

The controller method:

```
    public function store(){
    $data = request()->validate([
        'caption' => 'required',
        'image' => 'required',
    ]);

    $imagePath=request('image')->store('uploads','public');

    //interventionImage
     $image =Image::make(public_path("storage/{$imagePath}" ))- 
     >fit(1200,1200);
     $image->save();
    //changes to $data arrays

    auth()->user()->posts()->create([
        'caption' =>$data['caption'],
        'image' => $imagePath,
    ]);
    // \App\Post::create($data);


   return redirect('/profile/' .auth()->user()->id);
```

Html image:

```
     <img src="/storage/{{$postId->image}}" alt="photo is not available !" c 
   class="w-100">
```

I'm getting the below error

> "image source not readable error"

Comment: Are you using Homestead? If so, did you run `php artisan storage:link` in your guest machine or on your host? (It should be ran wherever the code executes, using homestead, that's inside your homestead guest machine)

Comment: no, i'm not using virtual machine. i'm using the php development server,   at first my project directory was in the xampp folder and after uploading image, there was a conflict between xampp storage folder and the laravel/storage folder. so, i moved my project to another drive @stokoe0990

Comment: do you have any route like `/storage/`? Because you can't access the `storage` folder directly by URL. You have only access of `public` by default.

Comment: the image source is using storage path:   <img src="/storage/...">  @VikashPathak

Comment: i would be really thankful if you help me @VikashPathak

Comment: Also did you tried `echo asset('storage/'.$postId->image);`

Comment: it's still not working and gives the "Intervention\Image\Exception\NotReadableException " error  @VikashPathak

Comment: remove `storage/` from here `$image =Image::make(public_path("storage/{$imagePath}" ))`

Comment: i removed that. it's not working @VikashPathak

Comment: i solved it . i should have first remove the storage folder in the "public/storage" then run the artisan command  "php artisan storage:link" again.  so it will add the photos in that folder. thanks a lot. @VikashPathak

Comment: Awesome.........